# Precision-Recall curve vs ROC curve : Should I still apply PR curve on already balanced information through SMOTE?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, random-forest, precision-recall

I built 3 different model in Random Forests for imbalanced binary classification problem. (0 - 369, 1- 1750)

First one is Random Forest (baseline) which uses rf1 fitting on trainX and trainY

Second one is Random Forest (balanced) which uses rf2 that configures class_weight = 'balanced' fitting on trainX and trainY.

Third one is Random Forest (SMOTE) which uses rf1 fitting on trainX_smote and trainY_smote.

I know that in normal practice, area under PR curve should be used for imbalanced data set. However, I am not too sure if I need to use area under PR curve or ROC curve again for 2nd and 3rd case..

Should I still apply area under PR curve for 2nd and 3rd case even if I sort of "balanced" data set using parameter or SMOTE process? I know that ROC AUC is not comparable to PR AUC but my understanding is you use PR AUC for imbalanced data only so I have dilemma.

My goal is to show if oversampling SMOTE or configuring parameter in class_weight = 'balanced' would improve predictive power or not.

Please let me know which one I should use for already balanced dataset and why. Thanks!

```
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.20, random_state=2019)

# First 2 models

# baseline model using imbalanced data
rf1 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2500, max_depth=4)

# balanced model using class_weight = 'balanced'
rf2 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2500, class_weight = 'balanced', max_depth=4)

# SMOTE
smote = SMOTE(random_state=42)
trainX_smote, trainY_smote = smote.fit_sample(trainX, trainY)

trainX_smote = pd.DataFrame(data = trainX_smote, columns=trainX.columns)

# 3rd model will use rf1 on SMOTEd trainX and trainY and then .fit and will test on original testX.
```